# rxjs subscription being called more often than expected

Tags: rxjs

I have a `BehaviorSubject` stream of functions. I have an `initialState` object represented as an `immutable Record`. Those functions are `scanned` and used to manipulate the state. The code looks like this:

```
const initialState = Record({
    todo: Record({
        title: "",
    }),
    todos: List([Record({title: "first todo"})()])
})

const actionCreator = (update) => ({
    addTodo(title) {
        update.next((state) => {
            console.log({title}); // for debugging reasons
            const todo = Record({title})()
            return state.set("todos", state.get("todos").push(todo))
        }) 
    },
    typeNewTodoTitle(title) {
        update.next((state) => state.set("todo", state.get("todo").set("title", title))
    })
})

const update$ = new BehaviorSubject(state => state);
const actions = actionCreator(update$);
const state = update$.pipe(
    scan(
        (state, updater) => updater(state), initialState()
    ),
    // share() without share weird things happen 
)
```

I have a very simple test written for this

```
it("should only respond to and call actions once", () => {
    const subscripition = chai.spy();
    const addTodo = chai.spy.on(actions, 'addTodo');
    const typeNewTodoTitle = chai.spy.on(actions, 'typeNewTodoTitle');
    state
      .pipe(
        map(s => s.get("todo")),
        distinctUntilChanged()
      )
      .subscribe(subscripition);

    state
      .pipe(
        map(s => s.get("todos")),
        distinctUntilChanged()
      )
      .subscribe(subscripition);

      actions.addTodo('test');
      expect(subscripition).to.have.been.called.twice // error
      actions.typeNewTodoTitle('test');
      expect(subscripition).to.have.been.called.exactly(3) // error

     expect(addTodo).to.have.been.called.once
     expect(typeNewTodoTitle).to.have.been.called.once
  });
});
```

The first strange behavior is that `subscription` has been called 3 times and then 4 instead of 2 and then 3 times. The second strange behavior is that even though each action has only been called once, the `console.log` has been called twice. I can fix this problem by adding `share()` to the pipeline, but I can't figure out why that's required.

Comment: Can you reproduce this in a [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com)?

Comment: Yes give me just a few minutes